# PIP button in iPhone Avplayer

Tags: swift, iphone, avplayer, picture-in-picture

I enabled Audio,AirPlay and Picture in Picture background modes in project's Capabilities.

My problem is this:

If I run app on iPad device I see the PiP button and I can enabled PiP mode. If I run app on iPhone device I don't see PiP button, but I don't understand why.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Open Xcode -> Go to Your project -> select "Signing and Capabilities" -> add new capability with "+" button. -> Add "Background Modes" Capability and check "Audio,AirPlay and Picture in Picture" (image below)[image: enabling PiP Capabilty] After that open your `AppDelegate` and add audio session support for PiP as in code below:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playback)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: [])
    } catch {
        print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
    }
    
    return true
}
```

After implementing all steps above, your PiP button should be present in your player.

Answer (score 0):

You propably do not have iOS 14+ on iPhone. For iPad iOS 13 is sufficient for PiP , but for iPhones it is only iOS 14 and higher.

Comment: Now it IOS 14.5

Comment: You also need to enable Picture in Picture in background mode and set avAudioSession, check this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/configuring_the_audio_playback_of_ios_and_tvos_apps

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your OS version, for my case I was using iOS 14.0 and now I upgrade to iOS 16 and that's works for me.